# how to show an image in p:dialog from a datable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm using primefaces to show a datable :

I have a column in my datable , it's an image , what i want is when i clic in the image , a p:dialog show the image with a big dimension .

I did it but the p:dialog show the wrong image, it shows the image of the last row in the datable .

```
<p:column headerText="imagePath">
  <h:graphicImage library="images" name="#{book.imagePath}.png" 
                  width="75px" onclick="PF('dlg').show();"/>
  <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" resizable="f" height="600px"width="500px"onShow="js">
    <h:graphicImage  library="images" name="#{book.imagePath}.png"width="400px"/>
  </p:dialog>
</p:column>
```

Thank you

**I have solved the problem with the commandlink component**

```
<p:column headerText="imagePath">
  <p:commandLink update=":zaki:foo:imgDlg1" oncomplete="dlg1.show()"
                 action="#{jsfClient.showImg(book)}">
    <h:graphicImage value="/resources/images/#{book.imagePath}.png" width="75px"/>
  </p:commandLink>
</p:column>
```

I have put in image into a commandlink and it works perfect , note that i have put the p:dialog out from the datable.

Comment: Did you copy-paste your code? Cuz you lost a `{` in the `h:graphicImage` of the `p:dialog`.

Comment: it's not the problem,have you an idea for my issues?

Comment: It seems to me you have several dialogs with widgetVar="dlg" in the page, so it'll probably just show() the last one. Instead I think you should have a single dialog outside the table, which reads the imagepath from a new attribute on the bean - remember the "rendered=..." attribute on the component. When you click the small image you must set this attribute in the bean, update the dialog via ajax and then show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should poll the dialog out of the dataTable and record which book did the user select before open the dialog.

Take a look at this code:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{imgBean.books}" var="book">
    <p:column headerText="imagePath">
        <h:commandButton image="/images/#{book.imagePath}.png" style="width: 75px" action="#{imgBean.showImg(book)}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<p:dialog  widgetVar="dlg" id="imgDlg" resizable="f" height="600px" width="500px">
    <h:graphicImage  value="../images/#{imgBean.selectedBook.imagePath}.png" width="400px"/>
</p:dialog>
```

The action of the commandButton looks like:

```
private Book SelectedBook;

public void showImg(Book book){
    this.SelectedBook=book;
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("imgForm:imgDlg");
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dlg').show()");
}

public Book getSelectedBook() {
    return SelectedBook;
}
```

In this way, you can not only show the image but also other information of the book.

BTW, you can also update/show the dialog in the `h:commandButton` instead of from backing Bean.

Comment: hello thank you very much , you response worked just the half , i could cal the method in the bean  but the image didn't appear in the page.for that i changed the type of component but it's the same reasoning thank you

Comment: The image didn't show in the dataTable or the dialog?

Comment: the dialog itself didn't appear .

Comment: I've tried these code and it works in my enviroment.

Comment: Then try to show dialog in the oncomplete event instead of the method in the backing bean.

Comment: i have checked the id for the form and for the dialog to be sure.the issu with your solution i can't cal the dialog from the bean , when i write the same thing in the page it works.

Comment: Good! Congratulation! :)

Comment: for your last proposition oncomplete dosen't exist in the h:commandbutton for that i choose a p:commandlink. thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is common widgetvar conflict. Think about how many p:dialogs are rendered in datatable and what is widgetvar of each? Inspect your rendered page to get better idea.

To resolve this issue either use some image id and pass it to custom javascript or create property (ex. "selectedBookImage") in your baking bean and refer it from  `<p:dialog>`

. Using this technique you can easily move p:dialog outside datatable.